# Clone TestStep from a Test Case to another Test Case using groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I use groovy script in my test suite to fill gaps in Automation. Here I need to clone a Property from one Test case to another Test Case. For Example.. Clone the Property test step from TestCase1 to TestCase2, In order to get values from that property.

I tried to get values in the property from one TC to another, But SOAPUI will not allow to do that action. we can't transfer a property value from one TC to another TC. So I go for cloning the Test step using groovy.

Your help is much appreciated.. Awaiting response from anyone..

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run TestCase2 from TestCase1 using test step "Run TestCase". Create properties that you need directly in TestCase2 so you can set them by "Property transfer" test step in TestCase1. More information about run test case [here](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/run-testcase.html) and about property transfer [here](http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/transferring-property-values.html).

Another way is to set properties and run TestCase programmatically. Something like this:

```
// get properties from testCase, testSuite or project if you need
def testCaseProperty = testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
def testSuiteProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
def projectProperty = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )
def globalProperty = com.eviware.soapui.SoapUI.globalProperties.getPropertyValue( "MyProp" )

//get test case from other project or from the same one
project = testRunner.getTestCase().getTestSuite().getProject().getWorkspace().getProjectByName(project_name)
testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName(suite_name);
testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName(testcase_name);

//set properties if you need
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(property_name, property_value);
testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue(another_property_name, another_property_value);

// run test case
runner = testCase.run(new com.eviware.soapui.support.types.StringToObjectMap(), false);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Artem, I use above grrovy code and it works perfectly. Actually i want to get value of that property and i use it as like..                                                              //get properties if you need
targetStep = testCase.getTestStepByName("Customer")
custID = targetStep.getPropertyValue("CustID1")
log.info custID

Answer (score 0):

The following example copies all of the properties from a test suite to the project that the test suite belongs in.

A similar mechanism could be used for test case properties, etc.

```
testSuite.getProperties().each {
    testSuite.getProject().setPropertyValue(it.getKey(), testSuite.getPropertyValue(it.getKey()))
}
```

To copy from one test case to another (I will leave defining the test cases)

```
def sourceTestCase = youdefinethis
def destTestCase = youdefinethis
sourceTestCase.getProperties().each {
    destTestCase.setPropertyValue(it.getKey(), sourceTestCase.getPropertyValue(it.getKey())
}
```